# Which methodology is inspired by Chomsky's innatist theory?

Tags: teaching-methods

I know that the Drilling/Audiolongual method was inspired by the Behaviorist theory.

I also know that communicative approach was inspired by Piaget's social-interactionist theory.

Which methodology is inspired by Chomsky/Krashen's innatist theory?

Comment: Hi. I'm a bit surprised to see the phrase "Chomsky/Krashen's innatist theory". In spite of agreements between Chomsky's and Krashen's theories, I thought they had worked independently; Chomsky basically killed the behaviourist theory of language acquisition quite some time before Krashen became a researcher. I am aware of Krashen's influence on language teaching but I don't know of a methodology directly based on Chomsky's theories (which doesn't mean they don't exist).